# SQL related fields and duplicates

Tags: sql

lets say i have a table like this. Table name: Logs

```
id time   prod   stan  amt
1  02:01  10     445   22
2  05:33  02     446   56
3  02:02  10     447   22
4  20:40  55     448   88
```

I want output as

```
id time   prod   stan  amt
1  02:01  10     445   22
3  02:02  10     447   22
```

This is what i ave tried

```
SELECT time, prod, stan, amt 
FROM Logs 
GROUP BY time, prod, stan, amt 
HAVING ( COUNT(prod) > 1 AND COUNT(amt) > 1 )
```

Here same values will be prod and amt. I want all the records because stan is different
Duplicate doesn't work 
can anyone help with a sql query

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? We will help you when you have a problem, not when you have a requirement. =)

Comment: Plus, it's not clear what the criteria is to get that output.

Comment: He could try using `SELECT * FROM Logs WHERE amt=22`

Comment: Yeah I'm getting only duplicates for this
SELECT time, prod, stan, amt
FROM Logs
GROUP BY time, prod, stan, amt
HAVING ( COUNT(prod) > 1 AND COUNT(amt) > 1 )

Comment: So far ok now we got how you get this result, but what do you expect?

Comment: it gives me only one record. I want both the records because time and stan is important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this SQL statment:

```
SELECT * FROM Logs l JOIN (
  SELECT prod, amt
  FROM Logs
  WHERE time between '02:00' and '06:00'
  GROUP BY prod, amt
  HAVING count(*)>1
) tmp
ON tmp.prod=l.prod AND tmp.amt=l.amt
WHERE time between '02:00' and '06:00'
```

I added some more rows to check that no unrelated rows will be added.

See also this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca583/2/0

Comment: thats good. can I limit it to a time like 02:00 to 06:00
This doesn't work

SELECT * FROM Logs 
where time between '02:00' and '06:00' l JOIN (
SELECT prod, amt
FROM Logs
GROUP BY amt, prod
HAVING count(*)>1 ) tmp
ON tmp.prod=l.prod AND tmp.amt=l.amt

Comment: I think I got it..it should be at the end, right?
Ok. I will check yours!

Comment: also is it possible to get records which triggered in seconds (like id 1 & 3) from same prod?